# Missing data in longitudinal data and fitted by linear mixed model

Tags: missing-data, lme4, mixed-models, mixed

I have a question about handling the following missing data scenario using the linear mixed effect model.

Suppose I have a closed longitudinal cohort followed by six years. There are 1500 individuals at the initial wave.
Available observations by each wave are as the following:

Wave 1: 1500
Wave 2: 1400
Wave 3: 1000
Wave 4: 800
Wave 5: 500
Wave 6: 67

There are two reasons for the missing observations. First, people dropped out. Second, the data collection process is ongoing, and not all individuals have been interviewed yet (this is more likely in the later wave).

I know the linear mixed effect model can address the missing problem using the maximum likelihood if MAR or MCAR. My question is: if I assume all missing happens at random, should I drop observations from wave 6 to avoid biased estimates? Or in other words, if I assume the missingness in my data set is happened at random, should I drop a specific wave with substantial amount of missingness to avoid a biased estimate?

The model I would like to run is as the following:

```
m_Kunkle_exe <- lmer(cs_exec_fn ~ PRS_Kunkle*AgeAtVisit*APOE_score + 
                   PRS_Kunkle*I(AgeAtVisit^2)*APOE_score +
                   + gender + EdYears_Coded_Max20 +  VisNo + famhist + X1  + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 +
                   (1 |family/DBID),
                 data = WRAP_all, REML = F)
```

Many thanks

Comment: ? I don't see a "wave 7" in your data description; did you mean "wave 6"?  Can you give an example of a formula (possibly simplified) that might describe your model? (It seems dangerous to assume that dropout is random, unless you know a lot about the dropout process ...)

Comment: @BenBolker, Hi Ben, I am sorry but I mean wave 6. I already fixed it in my question description. I added my model also in the question.